# Increment Counter after page auto refresh in PHP

Tags: php, html

I am very new to front end development so I am sorry if this is stupid. I am writing a webpage to display some info and I have the page auto refresh however, I would like to keep a counter static (i.e. not default to 0 after every refresh. 
What I have so far is

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>PAGE</title>
    <link rel=StyleSheet href=css/mycss.css type="text/css">
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="20">
</head>

<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['count'] = 0;
echo "<body>"
$output = "";

$output .= "<div class=\"page_title .sb-con\">DASHBOARD</div>

if(isset($_SESSION['count']) )
{
    echo "{$_SESSION['count']}\n";
$_SESSION['count'] = $_SESSION['count'] + 1;
}else{
    $_SESSION['count'] = 0;
}
echo $output;

echo "</body>";
echo "</html>";

?>
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: did you want every one to see the same counter value? or  each to have there own?

Comment: everyone to see the same

Comment: then you need to store the value in a file or db

Comment: sorry I misunderstood, same behavior for everyone but it could be different depending on when it was accessed

Comment: You always set it to 0 at the beginning : `$_SESSION['count'] = 0;`. Remove this line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to get this per user, then you can use PHP [sessions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php) :

The trick is to start a session, and then use `$_SESSION` global array to store your informations.
You can see simple examples of what you need [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php)

But if you need to store this information globally, for all users, then you will have to use a database. You can have a look at [this tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_intro.asp). You will find everything you need to understand and begin with MySQL.

Comment: nope wont work  based on your comment above, sessions are per person\computer

Comment: It doesn't seem to update the counter after the auto refresh, I have edited my question to show my new code

Answer (score 0):

Your code is ok but:

1.`session_start();`  you place it first and after `...<html><title>PAGE</title>`

2.you dont need: `$_SESSION['count'] = 0`; after `session_start();`

Your code `increment:$_SESSION['count']`, it works.